# Login to windows 8.1 when forgot password without internet access

Tags: windows-8.1

I am using Microsoft account for windows 8.1.
I forgot my password, and than I reset my password online(from another computer).
My account is only account(admin). 
Problem is that internet not working on my laptop so it does not know that I reset password from another computer. 
Any idea?

Comment: http://www.isunshare.com/windows-8-password/windows-8.1-password-reset-when-forgot-it.html

Comment: Activate the built-in Administrator account using [one of the answers here](http://superuser.com/q/72244/96662) and use that to fix the internet problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use "stick key" trick to reset the password offline.

you will required windows 8 installation disk(bootabl usb/cd) for this.
insert your bootabal windows drive into your laptop then boot from it

*Wait for the setup files to load, and select your language. Click Next.

*Click the Repair your computer link on the Install Windows screen.

*Select the operating system to repair, and note the drive letter on which the OS is installed (it is probably C: or D:). Click Next.(in cmd type address )(should refer some basic of cmd commands)

1. In the Command Prompt window, type copy c:\windows\system32\sethc.exe c:\ and press Enter.

2.Type copy /y c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe c:\windows\system32\sethc.exe and press Enter.

3. Exit the Command Prompt and reboot the computer. At the login screen, tap Shift five times. The Command Prompt will pop up.
4. Type "net user username password", replacing username with your username and password with a new password.
5. Exit the Command Prompt, and log in using your new password.

remember after that you have to reset the shift as sticky key again to do that

*1. Step through the instructions above to boot the PC using your Windows installation disc, open the recovery tools, and launch the Command Prompt.

2. Type copy /y c:\sethc.exe c:\windows\system32\sethc.exe and press Enter.
3. Exit the Command Prompt and reboot the computer. Pressing Shift five times will now activate Sticky Keys instead of the Command Prompt.

feel free to ask more details/quires on my ans...